# How SUM statement works in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm still learning and got stuck on this example in the PostgreSQL course:

```
SELECT customers.customer_name, SUM(products.price)
FROM order_details
LEFT JOIN products ON order_details.product_id = products.product_id
LEFT JOIN orders ON order_details.order_id = orders.order_id
LEFT JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id
GROUP BY customer_name
HAVING SUM(products.price) > 1000.00;
```

In this code, I don’t understand how the SUM operator works, it should simply sum the entire value from the price column in the products table, why does it give the sum for each name?  How does the program understand that I am asking to calculate the amount using the buyer’s name?

Comment: Because you told it to `...GROUP BY customer_name`. Read [Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html) and  [Aggregate Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

Comment: That's what you ask for: Give me the sum of all product prices for each customer_name. But only for customers that have at least a value over one thousand. But why do you use LEFT JOIN and not INNER JOIN?